# Why was this file (corrupted name) created?

Tags: 22.04, filename

I was taking a break from a project, doing something else. In the mean time this file was created in the project directory: `''$'\376''}Y'$'\016''+_'$'\356\245''1'$'\313''Y'$'\312''+'$'\270''>^'$'\321\312''1'$'\236\216\t\360''1'$'\355\227\031''3'$'\033\256\027\356''9?'$'\364\336\020''{ą'$'\254\301\254\355\235''<ߋ'$'\037''p'$'\252''G7͌ߔX8'$'\355\250''k'$'\267\a''ဵ'$'\202\236\a\271\341\256\333\021\235\211\343\224''3'$'\255''t'$'\036\020\330\301''Y'$'\266\027\216'`.

This project uses git. Using git logs, this file was created 12 minutes after a commit. I can't understand why this happened. I also know that I did nothing after the commit.

This file is also empty.

Edit:

It seems that there are two "corrupted" files:

```
--@--:~/--$ ls -l
total 1480
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ----- -----       0 -----  25 17:45 '^$3213121$236216t3601$3552270313$0332560273569?$364336020{ą$254301254355235'
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ----- -----       0 -----  25 17:44 '^��1��^I�1�^Y3^[�^W�9?��^P{ą����'
```

I removed some irrelevant things from the output.

Comment: Are you sure that nobody else did anything at your computer? Did you have any possibly buggy program running that may have created the file?

Comment: I'm 99.99% sure noone else did this. In terms of buggy programs, it's very unlikely (only reasonable potential one is `mtools`). I also didn't really do anything after the commit anyways.

Comment: This could in theory be a weird case of bitrot on my SSD, or some weird RAM bit flip close between buffer complete and write performed, or electronic problem on the SATA connection, or something similar.